# How can I mock useQuery from react-fetching-library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Hello how can I mock useQuery? I have container component which is responsible for calling an api, and simple ui component to display data for the user. I'm receiving current error

```
console.error node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:52
Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
```

Container

```js
import React from 'react';
import { screen, waitForElement, getByText } from '@testing-library/react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-fetching-library';

import { render } from 'tests';
import tags from 'api/mocks/tags-response.json';

import { TrendingTagsContainer } from './TrendingTagsContainer';
jest.mock('react-fetching-library');

describe('TrendingTagsContainer component', () => {
  test('should render component with correct title and description', async () => {
    const action = jest.fn();
    const useQuery = jest.fn(action());
    useQuery.mockReturnValue({ loading: false, error: false, query: () => true, payload: { tags } });
    console.log(useQuery());
    const { getByText } = render(<TrendingTagsContainer />);
    await waitForElement(() => screen.getByText('#Testing react'));
    expect(screen.getByText('#Testing react')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply you mock your `react-fetching-library` module as following:

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-fetching-library';

jest.mock('react-fetching-library');

// Everything looks the same I guess
```

Comment: Thanks, however this solution still try to fetch external api

Comment: ```Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
        at Object.dispatchError```

Comment: I’m not sure if useQuery will be called multiple times so try to mock all the time instead of just once by using mockImplentation

Comment: So the useQuery mock should be in a seprated folder and used with mockReturnValue instead? Sorry for the trivial questions I'm new to the testing.

Comment: Everything is supposed to be the same except for changing from mockReturnValueOnce to mockReturnValue.

Comment: Sorry, got same result with mockReturnValue, I don't know why it seems to skip the mock

Comment: Did you put jest.mock at the top level of your test module? Can you share your edited code again?

Comment: sure I will update the code above, the new error is the ClientContextProvider(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null. fortunately api is gone

Comment: Keep in mind do not put this mock: jest.mock('react-fetching-library') in any nested code like describe or test. Just put on top of the module

Comment: It is in the top of the file, it helped with resolving the error with calling api. Thanks!

Comment: Try to find out in your stack trace about that. Does it mean mock is working now?

Comment: Yes I don't have error with refused conection, now it's only about some test wrapper issue, Thank you very much.